# Joining 100GB tables on Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with 100gb data.

First table

```
+-------------+---------------+
| id          | code          |
+-------------+---------------+
| 10255911    |sample data    |
| 10255912    |sample data    |
| 10255913    |sample data    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Second table

```
+-------------+---------------+
| id          | code2         |
+-------------+---------------+
| 10255911    |sample data    |
| 10255912    |sample data    |
| 10255913    |sample data    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I need the fastest and optimal way to join tables for  creating view. With function UNION ALL very slooow. Table (VIEW) should be

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| id          | code          | code2       |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 10255911    |sample data    |sample data  |
| 10255912    |sample data    |sample data  |
| 10255913    |sample data    |sample data  |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You can create indexkey on column for performance.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE INDEX on ID Column of both Tables.

```
SELECT table_1.id
    , table_1.code 
    , table_2.code2
FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2
  ON table_1.id = table_2.id
  ;
```

Comment: Please post your explain plan .

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW stat AS
SELECT 
table.id,
table.code,
table.text,
table2.code2
FROM table INNER JOIN table2
  ON table.id = table2.id

Comment: No, I meant fire the query with EXPLAIN appended first. You have posted the view definition which I already understand you want to achieve. The performance of the view will be dependent upon the performance of SELECT .

Answer (score 0):

With 100 GBs of two tables, I don't think join is advisable. To run join query, you will need highest CPU, MEMORY, optimum mysql configuration etc. on your developer machine.

So better you merge these two tables into one. With this advantage, you may have to change your php application code to a bit to insert data into new table accordingly.

```
e.g. 
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| id          | code          | code2       |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 10255911    |sample data    |sample data  |
| 10255912    |sample data    |sample data  |
| 10255913    |sample data    |sample data  |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+

and then create index on Id field. 

If code and code2 fields are going to be used into where clause,
```

create a index for each of them too.